# Core Data no saving objects (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios9

I am trying save the core data objects from an array and while retrieving it, the objects I am getting are not having the updated values.

I believe I am doing something wrong while saving it.

Here's code :

```
func getAllHomeSectionsData(entity entity : NSString, data : NSArray) -> NSMutableArray {

        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = DKCoreDataManager.mainManagedObjectContext()

        data.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ object, index, stop in

            let homeSectionObject : NSDictionary  = object as! NSDictionary

            let homeSections  = HomeSections.insertInManagedObjectContext(managedObjectContext:context , entity: entity) as! HomeSections

            // Saving Section ID
            let homeSectionID = homeSectionObject.objectForKey("id" )?.integerValue
            homeSections.id = NSNumber(integer : homeSectionID!)


            // Saving Section Type
            let homeSectionType = homeSectionObject.objectForKey("type" )?.integerValue
            homeSections.type = NSNumber(integer : homeSectionType!)

            // Saving URL
            homeSections.url = homeSectionObject.objectForKey("url") as! NSString as String

        })

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }

        let array : NSMutableArray = DKCoreDataManager.getObjectsForEntity(entityName: entity, sortAscending: true, managedObjectContext:DKCoreDataManager.mainManagedObjectContext())

        return array
    }
```

Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What is DKCoreDataManager?

Comment: Call context.save() inside of "for loop" (enumerateObjectsUsingBlock)